# Making Celery works with RabbitMQ

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery

I can't make celery (version 4.0.2) works with RabbitMQ. I have the following in a tasks.py file (as suggested in the [tutorial/doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) of Celery):

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

But when I press this command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

I get the following weird error:

```
Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 22] Invalid argument.
```

My RabbitMQ server is running. Here is what I get when I press the "rabbitmqctl status" command:

```
[{pid,188},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.6"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.14"},
                        {rabbit_common,[],"3.6.6"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.11"},
                        {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.5"},
                        {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.",
                               "1.2.1"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.3.4"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.19.4"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.16.4"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,45625464},
          {connection_readers,0},
          {connection_writers,0},
          {connection_channels,0},
          {connection_other,0},
          {queue_procs,2704},
          {queue_slave_procs,0},
          {plugins,0},
          {other_proc,18736352},
          {mnesia,60216},
          {mgmt_db,0},
          {msg_index,51568},
          {other_ets,933528},
          {binary,1069976},
          {code,19343063},
          {atom,711569},
          {other_system,4716488}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,6819561472},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,188958461952},
 {file_descriptors,[{total_limit,1948},
                    {total_used,2},
                    {sockets_limit,1751},
                    {sockets_used,0}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,141}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,1138},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

Also I use Python 2.7.
Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem  ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a bug somewhere. I could have a trace of the error by running "celery ampq":

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 194, in <dictcomp>
  opt: sock.getsockopt(SOL_TCP, opt) for opt in TCP_OPTS
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
  return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I have downgraded Celery to version 3.1.23 and it now works fine. The problem might come from the fact that I use Celery on the version of Ubuntu integrated with Windows 10 (which is normally still suppose to be a "real" Ubuntu).